# Woocommerce Subscriptions Stripe Automatic Recurring payments not working

Tags: woocommerce, subscription, recurring

I used woocommerce product to subscribe automatic recurring payment through stripe payment gateway in my site.I have used woocommerce,woocommerce subscription,woocommerce stripe gateway plugins for this process.

First payment for subscription is working fine,but automatic recurring payment is not working with stripe.

Here are the plugin links that i have used.

http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/

Can anyone provide solution for this issue?

Comment: If you purchased that plugin you should contact [Woo Support](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us) and of course, make sure you have read the [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions)

Answer (score 1):

Please do reach out to our [support at WooThemes](https://support.woothemes.com) as we'd be happy to see what's happening here. Our official Subscriptions and Stripe extensions do work and have automatic recurring payments.

Here's a few things to check:

1. Be sure you have the latest version of WooCommerce, Stripe extension, and Subscriptions.
2. There may be a cron issue with your WordPress site. Try using [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) to find if there are any cron jobs that have been halted.
3. Find the scheduled payment that did not process and use the action scheduler to see if it was never fired. You can find this by navigating to `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=scheduled-action`. In the search box, enter {order_id}_ i.e. the ID of the order in which the subscription was purchased followed by an underscore. For example, for a subscription purchased in order 3125, the search string is 3125_.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have submitted the ticket  at WooThemes but they dont have respond last 1 day. I have checked cron is working but the subscription is not showing on my stripe account.

Comment: Nothing works, any other solution? Still waiting for woocommerce support no one replied yet.

Comment: @SandeepKumar What's your ticket number?

Comment: @SandeepKumar Subscriptions do not show in Stripe by the way. These are regular payments that are triggered via WooCommerce, not Stripe. This gives the store owner flexibility to trigger the payment from WooCommerce.

Comment: Thanks @Michael got it now and Recurring payment working as a regular payments.

Comment: @SandeepKumar what was the solution to get this working?  I am experiencing severe issues with recurring payments not working.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: @Michael if you have any insight to offer as well, please let me know.  My client is very unhappy due to this issue.

Comment: @SandeepKumar - what was the fix? I am getting the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

We've also struggled with Stripe payments not automatically renewing (the initial payment goes through but not any of the renewal payments). We did try WooThemes support but they couldn't find the order as it was made by another web design company so we didn't have access to the order details. Also, you'll find the log's aren't very verbose.

**The solution:**

Go to: WP-ADMIN > WooCommerce > Settings > Payments > Click "Manage" next to Stripe > Click the box next to "Saved Cards". This needs to be enabled or it won't take payment.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I know this is old. But I have used the solution but does that mean everyone that is already signed up will never renew properly?